# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

I have an excel file with 2 sheets and want update some values in 'Data' sheet.
I use the next simple commands:

```
var myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
var sql = "Update [Sheet2$] set Status = 'New_value' WHERE Building = 12";
var myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
myCommand.CommandText = sql;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get error:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException : Syntax error in UPDATE statement
```

I have also tried this:

```
var sql = "Update [Sheet2$] set Status = 'New_value' WHERE Building = '12'";
```

but with no success. What is wrong here?

Comment: Could you show your connection string? Do you use HDR=YES?

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion. I changed it to 'HDR=YES' and used second answer ([Status]) and it worked.

Comment: But it is necessary to put the square brackets after the HDR=YES?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

escape the column `status`

```
var sql = "Update [Sheet2$] set [Status] = 'New_value' WHERE Building = 12";
```